# How to insert null to Postgres from PHP

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have been working on a project management system and I'm coding it with PHP and PostgreSQL 8.4 and Model-View-Controller.

To put you people in context I will explain from the root (as short as I can).

I have a class called `Actividad` that extends a database abstraction class to execute the queries.

```
    class Actividad extends AbstraccionBD
    {      
    
    /**
     * Constructor de la clase
     *
     * @param String  $nom  Nombre 
     * @param String  $des  Descripción
     * @param String  $fi   Fecha de inicio
     * @param String  $fc   Fecha de culminación
     * @param Float   $pon  Ponderación
     * @param Boolean $crit Crítica
     * @param String  $le   Lugar Ejeucución
     * @param String  $rec  Recursos
     * @param Integer $pe   Presupuesto estimado
     * @param String  $est  Estado
     * @param Integer $cal  Calificación
     * @param Integer $peje Presupuesto ejecutado
     * @param Integer $asis Asistencia
     */
    public function __construct($nom, $des, $fi, $fc, $pon, $crit, $le, $rec, 
                                $pe, $est, $cal, $peje, $asis)
    {

        //Asignamos todos los valores especificados al 
        //objeto
        $this->nombre = $nom;
        $this->descripcion = $des;
        $this->fecha_inicio = $fi;
        $this->fecha_culminacion = $fc;
        $this->ponderación = $pon;
        $this->es_critica = $crit;
        $this->lugar_ejecucion = $le;
        $this->recursos = $rec;
        $this->presupuesto_est = $pe;
        $this->estado = $est;
        $this->calificacion = $cal;
        $this->presupuesto_ejec = $peje;
        $this->asistencia = $asis;
        
    }

    public function insertarObjeto()
    {
        //Construimos el query de inserción de datos en la tabla
        //actividad; nótese que se llama al procedimiento almacenado
        //sga.max_num_actividad(int,int) para determinar el número
        //de la actividad que se esta insertando.
        $this->_query = 
            "INSERT INTO sga.actividades " . 
                "(proyecto, ejec_proyecto, num_actividad, nombre, " . 
                "descripcion, fecha_inicio, fecha_culminacion, " .
                "ponderacion, critica, lugar_ejecucion, recursos, " . 
                "prepuesto_estimado, estado, calificacion, " . 
                "presupuesto_ejecutado, asistencia) " . 
            "VALUES " . 
                "($this->proyecto, $this->ejec_proyecto, " . 
                "sga.max_num_act($this->proyecto, $this->ejec_proyecto) + 1, " . 
                "'$this->nombre', " . 
                "'$this->descripcion', '$this->fecha_inicio', " . 
                "'$this->fecha_culminacion', $this->ponderación, " . 
                "$this->es_critica, '$this->lugar_ejecucion', " . 
                "'$this->recursos', $this->presupuesto_est, " . 
                "'$this->estado', $this->calificacion, " . 
                "$this->presupuesto_ejec, $this->asistencia);";
                
        //Ejecutamos el query de inserción
        $this->ejecutarQuery();
    }
```

(I was asked to keep it 80 chars per line for the project.)

**Table definition** (no FK taken in consideration):

```
CREATE TABLE sga.actividades
(
    proyecto integer NOT NULL,
    ejec_proyecto integer NOT NULL,
    num_actividad smallint NOT NULL,
    nombre character varying(150),
    descripcion character varying(500),
    fecha_inicio date NOT NULL,
    fecha_culminacion date NOT NULL,
    ponderacion numeric (3,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    critica boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    lugar_ejecucion character varying(100),
    recursos character varying(250),
    prepuesto_estimado integer,
    estado sga.estados_actividad NOT NULL, -- Dominio estados_actividad
    calificacion integer,
    presupuesto_ejecutado integer,
    asistencia smallint, 
    CONSTRAINT actividad_pkey
        PRIMARY KEY(proyecto, ejec_proyecto, num_actividad)
);
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is to pass the values from the model, 'something' like this:

```
    $a = new Actividad('Actividad1','DescA1', '14-07-14','14-07-14',0.00, 
                'false',null,null,0,'ACT',null, null, null);

    //Dont worry im using __set method
    $act->proyecto = 1;
    $act->ejec_proyecto = 1;

    $a->insertarObjeto();
```

As you can see I'm passing some `NULL` values in the constructor because in the DB those values can be null, all cool so far.

When I try to run it I get this query:

```
INSERT INTO sga.actividades 
    (proyecto, ejec_proyecto, 
    num_actividad, nombre, 
    descripcion, fecha_inicio, 
    fecha_culminacion,
    ponderacion, critica, 
    lugar_ejecucion, recursos, 
    prepuesto_estimado, estado, 
    calificacion, presupuesto_ejecutado, 
    asistencia) 
VALUES 
    (1, 1, sga.max_num_act(1, 1) + 1, 
    'Actividad1', 'DescA1', '14-07-14', 
    '14-07-14', 0, false, '', '', 0, 'ACT', , , );
```

Here's my problem: this query will never run because I'm using `NULL` keyword from PHP and when it's converted into a string in the 'concatenation madness', it stays empty (nothing in the string), so Postgres (as expected) sends the syntax error in the `(, , ,)` part.

I need to replace those empty strings (`''`) with the `NULL` keyword so that Postgres recognizes and inserts it correctly.

Also, some of the values passed in the constructor are wrapped into single quotes in the `insertarObjeto()` function (they are `character varying` in the DB).

And in Postgres `''` is not the same as `NULL`.

#### What I tried to fix this

One way is to put (N) if-else statements and concatenate the correct on each case (which is kind of ugly for future maintenance of the code and system expansions), something like this:

```
if(is_null($this->asistencia))
{
    $this->_query .= "null, ";
}
else
{
    $this->_query .= "$this->asistencia, ";
}
```

The problem in that approach is that there are to many attributes (and I have classes with far more that this one).

Another way I saw is to wrap null in single quotes in the constructor. That works for integer (bad solution I know), but those wrapped in single quotes already in the function will throw 'null' in the query, which is also wrong, i.e:

```
INSERT INTO sga.actividades 
        (proyecto, ejec_proyecto, 
        num_actividad, nombre, 
        descripcion, fecha_inicio, 
        fecha_culminacion,
        ponderacion, critica, 
        lugar_ejecucion, recursos, 
        prepuesto_estimado, estado, 
        calificacion, presupuesto_ejecutado, 
        asistencia) 
    VALUES 
        (1, 1, sga.max_num_act(1, 1) + 1, 
        'Actividad1', 'DescA1', '14-07-14', 
        '14-07-14', 0, false, 'null', 'null', 0, 'ACT', null ,null ,null );
```

Is there a better solution for this? Other than (n) if-else statements?

Comment: What pg_*() function(s) are you using? Show a really simple ~3-line example.

Comment: Ain't no such thing as "postgre". [The name is "PostgreSQL" or "Postgres" for short.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, My bad i will update the title, i didn't notice the typo. Also i will try your solution about the prepared statements, they look like the way to go on this.

Comment: @DwayneTowell im using ADODB for the execution of the postgres statements, i will check out how that library manages the prepared statements.

Comment: I think that for future people finding this error i'll put the table definition has well.

Comment: @GabrielVitale: Table definition is *always* a good idea.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, the prepared statements worked like a charm in this, and like you said the PHP null is used perfectly on them. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

#### 1. Omit columns

If you don't have defined column defaults, the default default (sic!) is `NULL`. You can just omit columns that should be `NULL`:

```
INSERT INTO sga.actividades 
        (proyecto, ejec_proyecto, 
        num_actividad, nombre, 
        descripcion, fecha_inicio, 
        fecha_culminacion,
        ponderacion, critica, 
        prepuesto_estimado, estado) 
VALUES 
        (1, 1, sga.max_num_act(1, 1) + 1, 
        'Actividad1', 'DescA1', '14-07-14', 
        '14-07-14', 0, false, 0, 'ACT');
```

Of course, if you alter column defaults for columns not mentioned here, you also alter the result of this `INSERT` - which may or may not be desirable.

#### 2. Use prepared statements

Then you can use PHP `NULL` values. And it's a good idea anyway to sanitize input and prevent possible SQL injection.

```
pg_prepare($pg_conn, 'insert1', "INSERT INTO sga.actividades (proyecto, ejec_proyecto, ..., lugar_ejecucion, ...) VALUES ($1, $2, ...)");

pg_exec($pg_conn, 'insert1', array(1, 1, ..., NULL, ...));
```

More in the manual on [`pg_prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php) and [pg_execute](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-execute.php).